# Código de um botão para desfazer uma ação em C#

Tags: c#

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um software de Bingo para a Igreja a qual eu frequento. [image: Tela Principal]

Ao apertar um botão de algum número qualquer, o mesmo irá aparecer no Picture Box ao lado. Como mostra a imagem seguinte.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora, percebam que existe o botão "<< Voltar", é nele que que preciso de ajuda. Preciso de um código para programá-lo para desfazer uma ação anterior.
Por exemplo: Apertei o botão 42 na tela, mas não era para ser ele, era para ser o 43, como disse: uma vez apertado ele fica inutilizado. O usuário apertaria o botão "<< Voltar" para desfazer a ação dele - que era habilitar novamente o botão "42".
Como faço isso?
Desde já, agradeço.

@Edit
A pedidos, meu código está assim:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn1 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\1.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn1;
        button1.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn2 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\2.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn2;
        button2.Enabled = false;
    }
    private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn3 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\3.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn3;
        button3.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn4 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\4.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn4;
        button4.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn5 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\5.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn5;
        button5.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn6 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\6.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn6;
        button6.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn7 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\7.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn7;
        button7.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn8 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\8.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn8;
        button8.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn9 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\9.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn9;
        button9.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn10 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\10.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn10;
        button10.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn11 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\11.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn11;
        button11.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn12 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\12.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn12;
        button12.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn13 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\13.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn13;
        button13.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn14 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\14.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn14;
        button14.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button15_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn15 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\15.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn15;
        button15.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button16_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn16 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\16.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn16;
        button16.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button17_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn17 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\17.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn17;
        button17.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button18_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn18 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\18.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn18;
        button18.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button19_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn19 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\19.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn19;
        button19.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button20_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn20 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\20.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn20;
        button20.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button21_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn21 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\21.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn21;
        button21.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button22_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn22 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\22.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn22;
        button22.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button23_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn23 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\23.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn23;
        button23.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button24_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn24 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\24.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn24;
        button24.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button25_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn25 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\25.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn25;
        button25.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button26_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn26 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\26.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn26;
        button26.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button27_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn27 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\27.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn27;
        button27.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button28_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn28 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\28.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn28;
        button28.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button29_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn29 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\29.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn29;
        button29.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button30_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn30 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\30.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn30;
        button30.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button31_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn31 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\31.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn31;
        button31.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button32_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn32 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\32.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn32;
        button32.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button33_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn33 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\33.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn33;
        button33.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button34_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn34 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\34.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn34;
        button34.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button35_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn35 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\35.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn35;
        button35.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button36_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn36 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\36.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn36;
        button36.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button37_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn37 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\37.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn37;
        button37.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button38_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn38 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\38.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn38;
        button38.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button39_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn39 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\39.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn39;
        button39.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button40_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn40 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\40.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn40;
        button40.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button41_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn41 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\41.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn41;
        button41.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button42_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn42 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\42.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn42;
        button42.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button43_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn43 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\43.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn43;
        button43.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button44_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn44 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\44.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn44;
        button44.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button45_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn45 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\45.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn45;
        button45.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button46_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn46 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\46.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn46;
        button46.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button47_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn47 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\47.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn47;
        button47.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button48_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn48 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\48.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn48;
        button48.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button49_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn49 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\49.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn49;
        button49.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button50_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn50 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\50.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn50;
        button50.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button51_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn51 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\51.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn51;
        button51.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button52_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn52 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\52.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn52;
        button52.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button53_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn53 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\53.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn53;
        button53.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button54_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn54 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\54.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn54;
        button54.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button55_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn55 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\55.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn55;
        button55.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button56_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn56 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\56.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn56;
        button56.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button57_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn57 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\57.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn57;
        button57.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button58_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn58 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\58.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn58;
        button58.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button59_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn59 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\59.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn59;
        button59.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button60_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn60 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\60.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn60;
        button60.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button61_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn61 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\61.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn61;
        button61.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button62_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn62 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\62.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn62;
        button62.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button63_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn63 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\63.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn63;
        button63.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button64_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn64 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\64.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn64;
        button64.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button65_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn65 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\65.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn65;
        button65.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button66_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn66 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\66.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn66;
        button66.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button67_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn67 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\67.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn67;
        button67.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button68_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn68 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\68.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn68;
        button68.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button69_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn69 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\69.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn69;
        button69.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button70_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn70 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\70.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn70;
        button70.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button71_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn71 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\71.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn71;
        button71.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button72_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn72 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\72.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn72;
        button72.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button73_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn73 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\73.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn73;
        button73.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button74_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn74 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\74.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn74;
        button74.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button75_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image btn75 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\75.jpg");
        img_box.Image = btn75;
        button75.Enabled = false;
    }


}
```

}

Comment: Coloque como está seu código, o que você já fez, já tentou. Dê alguma coisa para alguém te orientar de acordo com o que você está fazendo.

Answer (score 3):

Realmente a melhor forma de fazer o que você quer é usando uma pilha. Caso você não saiba o que é uma pilha de dados sugiro que comesse pesquisando o que é uma "pilha". Segue um link de um vídeo com uma explicação simples [Estrutura de dados Pilha em C#](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nHF_pgep9qE).

A baixo está o código de uma pequena classe para manipular o acesso a pilha e alterar a propriedade `Enabled` dos botões e logo em seguida esta o código do form que demonstra como a classe é usada sem ter que escrever código no evento `click` de cada um dos botões.

Qualquer dúvida é só perguntar.

Classe PilhaBotoes.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Bingo2._1
{
    public class PilhaBotoes
    {
        private Stack<Button> pilhaBotoes = new Stack<Button>();
        public string Adicionar(Button btn)
        {
            btn.Enabled = false;
            pilhaBotoes.Push(btn);

            return btn.Text;
        }
        public string Remover()
        {
            if (pilhaBotoes.Count == 0)
                return "";

            Button btn = pilhaBotoes.Pop();
            btn.Enabled = true;

            if (pilhaBotoes.Count == 0)
                return "";
            else
                return pilhaBotoes.Peek().Text;
        }
    }
}
```

Form1

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace Bingo2._1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        PilhaBotoes pilha;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            pilha = new PilhaBotoes();

            bt01.Click += buttonClick;
            bt02.Click += buttonClick;
            bt03.Click += buttonClick;
            bt04.Click += buttonClick;
            bt05.Click += buttonClick;
            bt06.Click += buttonClick;
            bt07.Click += buttonClick;
            bt08.Click += buttonClick;
            bt09.Click += buttonClick;
            bt10.Click += buttonClick;
            bt11.Click += buttonClick;
            bt12.Click += buttonClick;
            bt13.Click += buttonClick;
            bt14.Click += buttonClick;
            bt15.Click += buttonClick;
            bt16.Click += buttonClick;
            bt17.Click += buttonClick;
            bt18.Click += buttonClick;
            bt19.Click += buttonClick;
            bt20.Click += buttonClick;
        }

        private void buttonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lb_numero.Text = pilha.Adicionar((sender as Button));
        }

        private void bnt_desfazer_ultima_alteracao_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lb_numero.Text = pilha.Remover();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Me desculpe, mas sua resposta não seria uma duplicação da minha que eu respondi primeiramente? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/76673/298.
Quando você concorda que a solução para o problema é uma resposta já dada, então o correto é você apoiar a resposta já dada clicando na seta para cima.

Comment: Ambas usam pilha mas não iguais, a sua resposta utiliza uma pilha de int e uma função para obter o número quando um botão é clicado, eu utilizei uma pilha de botões ao desempilhar tenho o botão que desejo trabalhar, é tanto que meu evento só possui uma linha.

Outro ponto é a função para carregar um arquivo de imagem, sendo que é muito mais rápido passar a propriedade `Text` do botão para o label. Sem falar o risco do arquivo não existir.

Votos negativos devem ser dados a respostas erradas por favor releia "Quando devo votar contra?"(http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)

Answer (score 2):

Sugiro que você faça duas alterações em seu código.

1. A primeira alteração é criar um método a ser chamado no evento clique dos botões numéricos, o que irá remover bastante a duplicidade de seu código. Além disso, o formulário irá passar também a atribuir dinamicamente um mesmo evento click para todos os botões numéricos, em vez de você declará-los um por um manualmente.
2. A segunda alteração é adicionar uma pilha em seu formulário para guardar um histórico de todos os números selecionados pelo usuário, na ordem em que foram selecionados. Em C#, a pilha é um objeto da classe **System.Collections.Generic.Stack< T >**, em que `T` nesse caso pode ser um `int`, pois a pilha estará armazenando números (os números selecionados pelo usuário).

Bom, vamos então ao código. Primeiramente, declare um objeto Stack que irá representar o histórico de números selecionados em seu formulário da seguinte forma (lembre-se de importar o namespace `System.Collections.Generic` com uma diretiva `using` no topo do arquivo de código fonte do formulário):

```
private Stack<int> _historicoDeNumerosSelecionados = new Stack<int>();
```

O **método a ser chamado no evento clique de cada botão** deve ser o seguinte:

```
private void ProcesseEscolhaDoUsuario(int numeroSelecionado)
{
    img_box.Image = ObtenhaImagemDoBotao(numeroSelecionado);

    // Encontra o botão clicado.
    var botaoClicado = ObtenhaBotaoNumerico(numeroSelecionado);
    botaoClicado.Enabled = false;

    // Adiciona o número selecionado no histórico.
    _historicoDeNumerosSelecionados.Push(numeroSelecionado);
}

public Button ObtenhaBotaoNumerico(int numeroDoBotao)
{
    return this.Controls.Find("button" + numeroDoBotao) as Button;
}

public Image ObtenhaImagemDoBotao(int numeroSelecionado)
{
    return Image.FromFile(string.Concat(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo 2.0\Img\", numeroSelecionado, ".jpg"));
}
```

No construtor do formulário você deve colocar o código abaixo, o qual **atribue dinamicamente o evento Click para os botões numéricos**:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    AtribuaEventosClickDosBotoesNumericos();
}

public void AtribuaEventosClickDosBotoesNumericos()
{
    // Itera os 75 botões numéricos.
    for (int i = 1; i <= 75; i++)
    {
        var botaoNumerico = ObtenhaBotaoNumerico(i);

        // Atribui o evento click para cada um dos botões numéricos.
        botaoNumerico.Click += BotaoNumerico_Click;
    }
}

// Evento a ser executado quando o usuário clicar em qualquer dos botões numéricos.
private void BotaoNumerico_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Obtém o número do botão clicado. Ex: button1 => numero = 1.
    string numeroDoBotao = ((Button)sender).Name.Replace("button", "");

    // Passa o número do botão para o método que irá efetuar o processamento 
    // do número selecionado. Por exemplo, no caso do button2, passa o
    // número 2, e no caso do button3 passa o número 3, etc.
    ProcesseEscolhaDoUsuario(int.Parse(numeroDoBotao));
}
```

Dado que o evento `BotaoNumerico_Click` será atribuído a todos os botões numéricos, você pode agora remover de seu código todas as declarações de evento dos botões, desde `button1_Click` até `button75_Click`. Com essa refatoração nós removemos aproximadamente 450 linhas de código duplicado.

Agora no **evento clique do botão Voltar** você faz o processo reverso com base no último número que foi adicionado na pilha:

```
public void BotaoVoltar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Obtém e remove do histórico o último número que foi selecionado.
    int ultimoNumeroSelecionado = _historicoDeNumerosSelecionados.Pop();

    // A imagem deverá agora mostrar o penúltimo número selecionado, por
    // isso precisamos "espiar" a pilha para verificar qual é agora o último
    // elemento (o qual anteriormente era o penúltimo).
    var penultimoNumeroSelecionado = _historicoDeNumerosSelecionados.Peek()
    img_box.Image = ObtenhaImagemDoBotao(penultimoNumeroSelecionado );

    // Encontra o último botão clicado.
    var ultimobotaoClicado = ObtenhaBotaoNumerico(ultimoNumeroSelecionado);

    // Habilita novamente o último botão clicado.
    ultimobotaoClicado.Enabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá, vendo seu código vou lhe dar uma sugestão, não seria melhor você usar no lugar da imagem um label e setar os valores dos números nele. Ex: no click do botão 1 você utiliza

`btn1 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo2.0\Img\1.jpg");
img_box.Image = btn1;`

Não seria mais viável você utilizar assim:

```
 label1.Text = "1";
```

Por que assim você vai gastar menos tempo e seu código vai ficar mais limpo e vai te dar menos trabalho por que ao inves de  colocar em cada evento de click no botão um código deste

```
    btn1 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo2.0\Img\1.jpg");
    img_box.Image = btn1;

 btn2 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Dudu\Desktop\Softwares\Bingo2.0\Img\2.jpg");
    img_box.Image = btn2;
```

Coloca este:

```
label1.text="1";
label1.text="2";
```

Isto é apenas uma sugestão, pois o código é seu e você pode programar do seu jeito :) .
A questão de clicar no botão de Voltar e desfazer a ultima alteração, isto pode ser feito utilizando o registro do windows para gravar o ultimo valor.
Exemplo de um código que eu fiz para fazer o teste:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Win32;
namespace Bingo2._0
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void bt1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\\Bingo2.0\\");
            key.SetValue("restaurar", "1");
            lb_numero.Text = "1";
            bt1.Enabled = false;

        }

        private void bt2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\\Bingo2.0\\");
            key.SetValue("restaurar", "2");
            lb_numero.Text = "2";
            bt2.Enabled = false;

        }

        private void bt3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\\Bingo2.0\\");
            key.SetValue("restaurar", "3");
            lb_numero.Text = "3";
            bt3.Enabled = false;

        }

        private void bt4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\\Bingo2.0\\");
            key.SetValue("restaurar", "4");
            lb_numero.Text = "4";
            bt4.Enabled = false;

        }

        private void bt5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\\Bingo2.0\\");
            key.SetValue("restaurar", "5");
            lb_numero.Text = "5";
            bt5.Enabled = false;

        }

        private void bt6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\\Bingo2.0\\");
            key.SetValue("restaurar", "6");
            lb_numero.Text = "6";
            bt6.Enabled = false;

        }

        private void bt7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\\Bingo2.0\\");
            key.SetValue("restaurar", "7");
            lb_numero.Text = "7";
            bt7.Enabled = false;

        }

        private void bt8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\\Bingo2.0\\");
            key.SetValue("restaurar", "8");
            lb_numero.Text = "8";
            bt8.Enabled = false;

        }

        private void bt9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\\Bingo2.0\\");
            key.SetValue("restaurar", "9");
            lb_numero.Text = "9";
            bt9.Enabled = false;

        }

        private void bt10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\\Bingo2.0\\");
            key.SetValue("restaurar", "10");
            lb_numero.Text = "10";
            bt10.Enabled = false;

        }

        private void bt11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\\Bingo2.0\\");
            key.SetValue("restaurar", "11");
            lb_numero.Text = "11";
            bt11.Enabled = false;

        }

        private void bt12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\\Bingo2.0\\");
            key.SetValue("restaurar", "12");
            lb_numero.Text = "12";
            bt12.Enabled = false;

        }

        private void bt13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\\Bingo2.0\\");
            key.SetValue("restaurar", "13");
            lb_numero.Text = "13";
            bt13.Enabled = false;

        }

        private void bt14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\\Bingo2.0\\");
            key.SetValue("restaurar", "14");
            lb_numero.Text = "14";
            bt14.Enabled = false;


        }

        private void bt15_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\\Bingo2.0\\");
            key.SetValue("restaurar", "15");
            lb_numero.Text = "15";
            bt15.Enabled = false;

        }

        private void bnt_desfazer_ultima_alteracao_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string pegarValorRegistro = (string)Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Bingo2.0", "restaurar", null);

            try
            {

                if (pegarValorRegistro == "1")
                {
                    bt1.Enabled = true;

                }
                else if (pegarValorRegistro == "2")
                {
                    bt2.Enabled = true;
                }

                else if (pegarValorRegistro == "3")
                {
                    bt3.Enabled = true;
                }

                else if (pegarValorRegistro == "4")
                {
                    bt4.Enabled = true;
                }
                else if (pegarValorRegistro == "5")
                {
                    bt5.Enabled = true;
                }
                else if (pegarValorRegistro == "6")
                {
                    bt6.Enabled = true;
                }
                else if (pegarValorRegistro == "7")
                {
                    bt7.Enabled = true;
                }

                else if (pegarValorRegistro == "8")
                {
                    bt8.Enabled = true;
                }
                else if (pegarValorRegistro == "9")
                {
                    bt9.Enabled = true;
                }

                else if (pegarValorRegistro == "10")
                {
                    bt10.Enabled = true;
                }
                else if (pegarValorRegistro == "11")
                {
                    bt11.Enabled = true;
                }

                else if (pegarValorRegistro == "12")
                {
                    bt12.Enabled = true;
                }

                else if (pegarValorRegistro == "13")
                {
                    bt13.Enabled = true;
                }

                else if (pegarValorRegistro == "14")
                {
                    bt14.Enabled = true;
                }

                else if (pegarValorRegistro == "15")
                {
                    bt15.Enabled = true;
                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Erro");
            }


        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Caso você queira vou deixar o link do projeto para voce fazer o download.
http://www.mediafire.com/download/423dw34fec9n2l7/Bingo2.0.rar

Obrigado...

Comment: Cara, tu usa win10? Se não, como tu fez para a borda de cima do form ficar desse jeito?

Comment: é o Windows 10 mesmo eu estou testando ele!

Comment: Não, o meu é o Windows 7 mesmo. Não sei como ela fica assim, para mim é normal.